# Confusion with key error python

Tags: python, keyerror

Ok so I asked for help with this code earlier today and got it fixed now I'm getting a weird error that I would like some advice or help getting fixed. The error that keeps popping up is

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HatterX/Desktop/CSV_Reader_and_Writer2_vPC3", line 27, in <module>
    fr_name = frow['Franchise'].strip()
KeyError: 'Franchise'"
```

any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv, datetime

franchiseList = {}

with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'r') as ff:
fcf = csv.DictReader(ff)
for frow in fcf:
    franchiseList[frow['Misc Franchise Name']] = frow
for Frow in fcf:
    franchiselist[Frow['FRANCHISE Name - Directory']] = Frow

newrow={'Last Sale Date': '', 'Last Sale Amount': '', 'First Name': '', 'Last Name': '', 'Email Address': '', 'Franchise': '', 'State': '', 'Postal/Zip Code': '', 'Last Web Order ID': '', 'Date Added': '', 'Email Source':'', 'osg_web_dir': ''}
new_field_names = newrow.keys()

with open('SOR935csv_(1).csv', 'r') as f1, open('FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'wb') as f2:
cf1 = csv.DictReader(f1, fieldnames=('CustNo1', 'CustNo2', 'LastOrderDate', 'LastOrderAmount', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserNo', 'EmailAddress', 'Franchise', 'PrevOrderDate', 'PrevOrderAmount', 'State', 'ZIP', 'Amt1', 'Amt2', 'Amt3', 'SalesPerson', 'WEBID'))
cf2 = csv.DictWriter(f2, new_field_names)
cf2.writeheader()
for row in cf1:
    nr = newrow
    nr['Last Sale Date'] = row['LastOrderDate'].strip()
    nr['Last Sale Amount'] = row['LastOrderAmount'].strip()
    nr['First Name'] = row['FirstName'].strip()
    nr['Last Name'] = row['LastName'].strip()
    nr['Email Address'] = row['EmailAddress'].strip().split(',',1)[0]

    fr_name = frow['Franchise'].strip()
    if fr_name in franchiseList:
                nr['Franchise'] = franchiseList[fr_name]['FRANCHISE Name'].strip()
    else:
        nr['Franchise'] = 'SHOP'

    nr['State'] = row['State'].strip()
    nr['Postal/Zip Code'] = row['ZIP'].strip()
    nr['Last Web Order ID'] = row['WEBID'].strip()
    nr['Date Added'] = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    fr_Name = Frow['osg_web-dir'].strip()
    if fr_Name in franchiselist:
                nr['osg_web_dir'] = franchiselist[fr_Name]['FRANCHISE Name - Directory'].strip()
    else:
        nr['osg_web_dir'] = 'shop'

    #nr['osg_web_dir'] = row['SalesPerson'].strip()
    nr['Email Source'] = 'FACTSauto'
    print nr
    cf2.writerow(nr)


import csv

franchiseList = {}

with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'r') as ff:
fcf = csv.DictReader(ff)
for frow in fcf:
    franchiseList[frow['Misc Franchise Name']] = frow

newrow={'Last Sale Date': '', 'Last Sale Amount': '', 'First Name': '', 'Last Name': '', 'Email Address': '', 'Franchise': '', 'State': '', 'Postal/Zip Code': '', 'Last Web Order ID': '',  'osg_web_dir': ''}
new_field_names = newrow.keys()

with open('SOR935csv_(1).csv', 'r') as f3, open('FACTS_bronto_import_update.csv', 'wb') as f4:
cf3 = csv.DictReader(f3, fieldnames=('CustNo1', 'CustNo2', 'LastOrderDate', 'LastOrderAmount', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserNo', 'EmailAddress', 'Franchise', 'PrevOrderDate', 'PrevOrderAmount', 'State', 'ZIP', 'Amt1', 'Amt2', 'Amt3', 'SalesPerson', 'WEBID'))
cf4 = csv.DictWriter(f4, new_field_names)
cf4.writeheader()
for row in cf3:
    nr = newrow
    nr['Last Sale Date'] = row['LastOrderDate'].strip()
    nr['Last Sale Amount'] = row['LastOrderAmount'].strip()
    nr['First Name'] = row['FirstName'].strip()
    nr['Last Name'] = row['LastName'].strip()
    nr['Email Address'] = row['EmailAddress'].strip().split(',',1)[0]

    fr_name = frow['Franchise'].strip()
    if fr_name in franchiseList:
                nr['Franchise'] = franchiseList[fr_name]['FRANCHISE Name'].strip()

    nr['State'] = row['State'].strip()
    nr['Postal/Zip Code'] = row['ZIP'].strip()
    nr['Last Web Order ID'] = row['WEBID'].strip()
    nr['osg_web_dir'] = row['SalesPerson'].strip()
    print nr
    cf4.writerow(nr)





#with open('SOR935csv_(1).csv', 'rb') as f1, \
#     open('FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'ab') as f2:
#    for inrow in f1:
#        outrow = {
#        outrow[0] = str(inrow[2])
#        f2.write(', '.join(outrow))
```

Comment: Can you double check that your indentation is correct? I get an `IndentationError` just after the first `with`. And on the line `fr_name = frow['Franchise'].strip()`, you refer to `frow` but you're well outside of the `for frow in fcf` loop. (That's syntactically allowed, but rarely makes logical sense to do)

Answer (score 1):

I think the line

```
fr_name = frow['Franchise'].strip()
```

Should be

```
fr_name = row['Franchise'].strip()
        # ^ note
```

`frow` is a `for` loop variable from elsewhere in your code (and will still have the last value it took in that loop), whereas `row` is the data you are currently processing.